# Remove whitespace from matplotlib heatplot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a heatplot in matplotlib for which I want to remove the whitespace to the north and east of the plot, as shown in the image below.
[image]

here is the code I'm using to generate the plots:

```
# plotting
figsize=(50,20)
y,x = 1,2
fig, axarry = plt.subplots(y,x, figsize=figsize)
p = axarry[1].pcolormesh(copy_matrix.values)

# put the major ticks at the middle of each cell
axarry[1].set_xticks(np.arange(copy_matrix.shape[1])+0.5, minor=False)
axarry[1].set_yticks(np.arange(copy_matrix.shape[0])+0.5, minor=False)

axarry[1].set_title(file_name, fontweight='bold')

axarry[1].set_xticklabels(copy_matrix.columns, rotation=90)
axarry[1].set_yticklabels(copy_matrix.index)

fig.colorbar(p, ax=axarry[1])

Phylo.draw(tree, axes=axarry[0])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use `ax.axis('tight')`.

By default, matplotlib tries to choose "even" numbers for the axes limits.  If you want the plot to be scaled to the strict limits of your data, use `ax.axis('tight')`.  `ax.axis('image')` is similar, but will also make the cells of your "heatmap" square.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Note the non-"even" size... (not a multiple of 2, 5, or 10)
data = np.random.random((73, 78))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=3)
for ax, title in zip(axes, ['Default', 'axis("tight")', 'axis("image")']):
    ax.pcolormesh(data)
    ax.set(title=title)

axes[1].axis('tight')
axes[2].axis('image')

plt.show()
```

[image]